# how to atomically add a new value to array field firebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I want to atomically add a new value to the 'atrr' array field and read it

[image]

[image]

I use Pyrebase.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture you show is of the Firebase Realtime Database, yet in your code you're trying to use the `firestore.ArrayUnion` operator that only exists on Cloud Firestore. While both Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and have different APIs.

There is no equivalent of the `ArrayUnion` operator for the Realtime Database. In fact, to store this structure on Realtime Database it is more common to do:

```
{
  "S": true,
  "M": true,
  "L": true,
  "XL": true
}
```

With this structure, you can add XXL to it with:

```
db.child("attr").update({ "XXL": true });
```